# Objective-C NSKeyedUnarchiver unloading

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

In some AppDelegate class I have property `NSDictionary *dict;`

In `applicationDidFinishLaunching` i'm loading it like:

```
dict = (NSDictionary*) [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:
                       @"/Users/username/Desktop/storage"];
```

Then, I have Outlet for button click. But inside click-action handler I could not access to dict's elements. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
here's .h-file:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface tttAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    NSWindow *window;
    NSDictionary *dict;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
- (IBAction)click:(id)sender;

@end
```

and .m-file:

```
#import "tttAppDelegate.h"

@implementation tttAppDelegate

@synthesize window;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    dict = (NSDictionary*) [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:@"/some/storage"];

     NSLog(@">>>>>>> %@", [dict valueForKey:@"test"]); // ok
}

- (IBAction)click:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@">>>>>>> %@", [dict valueForKey:@"test"]); // fail
}
@end
```

Comment: Please post more of your code. Is dict an instance variable?

Comment: One more question: Are you using ARC (Automatic Reference Counting), or manual memory management?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use property accessors instead of directly accessing your instance variables:

In your .h file:

```
@interface tttAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    NSWindow *window;
    NSDictionary *dict;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *dict;

- (IBAction)click:(id)sender;

@end
```

In your .m:

```
@implementation tttAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize dict;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    self.dict = (NSDictionary*) [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:@"/some/storage"];

     NSLog(@">>>>>>> %@", [self.dict valueForKey:@"test"]); // ok
}

- (IBAction)click:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@">>>>>>> %@", [self.dict valueForKey:@"test"]); // fail
}
@end
```

There are several reasons for doing this, but the most important in this case is that that way the accessor methods can handle memory management of the instance variable.